# Linux server directory port 8080

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, ubuntu

I access a java program by url  "http://{ip}:8080/ws/rest/Geral/consulta?token=XXXXX" Now I need to modify it.
It is hosted on a ubuntu aws. and I have access via ssh, but how can I find this file? in that directory can find it?

Comment: Assuming that it is that "java program" that is listening on that port you probably should start by finding the process that did bind to that port: `netstat --listen`

Comment: returned it, how do I get the information? https://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_2016-11-06_as_16-26-34-png @arkascha

Comment: Interesting... Have a try with that one: `nmap -sT -O localhost`

Comment: The program 'nmap' is currently not installed. @arkascha

Comment: Well, you _could_ install it... `sudo apt-get install nmap`

Comment: Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.00019s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports.
PORT     STATE SERVICE.
22/tcp   open  ssh.
8080/tcp open  http-proxy
No exact OS matches for host.
TCP/IP fingerprint: [...]
Network Distance: 0 hops @arkascha